# Linux Ubuntu Shell Script Infinite loop

Tags: linux, shell

So my script looks like this

```
java -jar asd.jar -a 32
java -jar asd.jar -a 33
java -jar asd.jar -a 36
java -jar asd.jar -a 34
Source /home/surge/stuff/r.sh
```

The script name is called r.sh
I did the permissions thing to make it executable.

For some reason, it won't loop. It just stops working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mark file as shel script: `#!/bin/bash`
2. change `Source` to `source`, shell commands are case sensitive

But better try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    java -jar asd.jar -a 32
    java -jar asd.jar -a 33
    java -jar asd.jar -a 36
    java -jar asd.jar -a 34
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Source` with `exec`. But it's still ugly soluton for making loops.